# Mongodb Find command for Json data inner loop

Tags: json, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and learning things now. Here, I encountered the following question which I am not able to query. Below is my JSON data and when I am trying to find "title": "ERP" by using following db.ERP.find( { "title" : "ERP" } ) it is not fetching any data even though there is data. Also, what would be the statement for finding data "identifier" : "0750652071" ,"categories" : [                 "Business & Economics"] .

Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this?

Json Data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a6d9c13cd5c314da703c80"), 
    "kind" : "books#volumes", 
    "totalItems" : NumberInt(1088), 
    "items" : [
        {
            "kind" : "books#volume", 
            "id" : "7r2cTflTfpQC", 
            "etag" : "sEiEfpm5JFQ", 
            "volumeInfo" : {
                "title" : "ERP",
                "subtitle" : "The Implementation Cycle", 
                "authors" : [
                    "Stephen Harwood"
                ], 
                "publisher" : "Butterworth-Heinemann", 
                "publishedDate" : "2003", 
                "industryIdentifiers" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "ISBN_10", 
                        "identifier" : "0750652071"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "type" : "ISBN_13", 
                        "identifier" : "9780750652070"
                    }
                ], 
                "readingModes" : {
                    "text" : false, 
                    "image" : true
                }, 
                "pageCount" : NumberInt(183), 
                "printType" : "BOOK", 
                "categories" : [
                    "Computers"
                ], 
                "averageRating" : 4.0, 
                "ratingsCount" : NumberInt(2), 
                }, 
            "saleInfo" : {
                "country" : "US", 
                "saleability" : "NOT_FOR_SALE", 
                "isEbook" : false
            }
         }, 
        {
            "kind" : "books#volume", 
            "id" : "3j86qt9VQ2kC", 
            "etag" : "MQN5u7Pj6yo", 
            "volumeInfo" : {
                "title" : "ERP: Making It Happen", 
                "subtitle" : "The Implementers' Guide to Success with Enterprise Resource Planning", 
                "authors" : [
                    "Thomas F. Wallace", 
                    "Michael H. Kremzar"
                ], 
                "publisher" : "John Wiley & Sons", 
                "publishedDate" : "2002-07-15", 
                "industryIdentifiers" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "ISBN_13", 
                        "identifier" : "9780471217039"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "type" : "ISBN_10", 
                        "identifier" : "0471217034"
                    }
                ], 
                "readingModes" : {
                    "text" : false, 
                    "image" : true
                }, 
                "pageCount" : NumberInt(384), 
                "printType" : "BOOK", 
                "categories" : [
                    "Business & Economics"
                ],
                "averageRating" : 4.0, 
                "ratingsCount" : NumberInt(4), 
                }, 
            "saleInfo" : {
                "country" : "US", 
                "saleability" : "FOR_SALE", 
                "isEbook" : true 
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: If it does not return any data, make sure you type everything correctly. `db` is the handle to the currently used database, no caps.

Comment: Thank you for swift reply.  when i tried like this it is not returning any data.  db.ERP.find ( {"identifier" : "0750652071", "categories" : "Business & Economics"})

Comment: Because your query is wrong, it does not match anything, so it does not return anything. You have an items array which contains a bunch of sub document elements. Search Google for "mongodb dot notation" and/or "$elemMatch" operator. You will see the reference doc for everything you need to know to work with mongodb.

Comment: Thank you for the hint .. i tried like this  db.ERP.find(
   {
     items:
       {
          $elemMatch:
            {
               title: 'ERP'
               
            }
       }
    }
)   didnt give any results

Comment: How about db.ERP.find( { items: { $elemMatch: { volumeInfo.title: 'ERP' } } } ) ?

Comment: When tried with db.ERP.find( { items: { $elemMatch: { volumeInfo.title: 'ERP' } } } )  it is throwing error saying cannot execute as they contains error at line 1 ,position 38: volumeInfo. ; position54:. ; Position 56: 'ERP'; Position 64: }. ; position66: }.

Answer (score 0):

To Search data where `tile` is `ERP` use following syntax :

```
db.collection.find({"items.volumeInfo.title":"ERP"})
```

To find data with `identifier` : `0750652071` and `categories` : `[ "Business & Economics"]` use following syntax :

```
db.collection.find({ "items.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.identifier" : "0750652071", "items.volumeInfo.categories" : { $in : [ "Business & Economics"] } })
```

If you wants only first item which match your criteria include following field in your query `{"items.$" : 1}` as below :

```
db.collection.find(
                    { 
                        "items.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.identifier" : "0750652071", 
                        "items.volumeInfo.categories" : { $in : [ "Business & Economics"] } 
                    },
                    { "items.$" : 1 }
                );
```

Comment: thanks for the hint .. I tried didn't give me any result. appreciate your help

Comment: have you changed collection name?

Comment: Yes, I did change collection name to 'ERP'. However, when in used the below statement                                                                              db.ERP.find({ "items.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.identifier" : "0750652071", "items.volumeInfo.categories" : { $in : [ "Business & Economics"] } })                                                                                       it is returning all the two item details, but i am expecting one item details to be fetched.                                                                      Thanks in advance!